# How can I concatenate something to the front of a string?

Tags: string, rust, string-concatenation

I keep getting the error "Use of moved value".

```
let mut s = "s".to_string();
s = s + &s;
```

Answer (score 4):

Think about what `+` desugars to:

```
s = s.add(&s);
```

Now this `add` is [from the `Add` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#tymethod.add) and is effectively this:

```
fn add(self: String, rhs: &str) -> String;
```

The use of `self` means that it is taking ownership of the string; you obviously can’t pass a reference to that as the second argument, because it isn’t yours any more.

You might think that it’d be OK doing this, but it’s not; the whole class is unsound, constituting mutable aliasing—both a mutable and immutable reference to the same thing existing at the same time. For this specific case, one way I could imagine it going wrong if permitted is if the string pushing were to reallocate the string; `rhs` would then conceivably be pointing to non-existent memory when it actually went to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a solution to Chris Morgan's answer:

```
let s = "s";
let mut double_s = s.to_owned(); // faster, better than to_string()
double_s = double_s + s;
```

You could also use

```
double_s.push_str(s);
```

instead of the last line.

Comment: Is there a method to `push_str` to the start of `double_s`?

Comment: Yes. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.insert_str